# How to configure Google to only search for SSL/TLS-encrypted websites?

Tags: tls, http

Is there a way to configure the Google Search Engine to only search for SSL/TLS-encrypted websites?

What I mean by that is that when I google something, only websites with a valid HTTPS certificate should appear in the search results. In this way I would like to communicate only encrypted with each website.

I found something like Google Programmable Search Engine. I am now struggling to configure the HTTPS-pattern of the websites to search (see the screenshots below).
[image]
[image]
But I think the Google Programmable Search Engine is not what I looking for, because it looks like more a custom JavaScript-Widget that I can integrate into my website.

Comment: *"In this way I would like to communicate only encrypted with each website."* - this is not what you get, even if Google Search would show only HTTPS results. A site can redirect to some plain HTTP site or contain such links and this is outside of the control of the search. If you want to use only HTTPS you need to enforce this at the client (i.e. browser) level, not at the level of a search engine.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: SEO rankings often sort themselves out naturally. Unless you're searching for something extremely specific, or end up pages deep into a Google search, the top ranked sites will likely employ TLS. If not, their SEO rankings are impacted, making them less visible in searches, or harder to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-inurl "https://"`
Google search operator could be the thing you are looking for.